# Flybuck circuit

Tags: buck

Needing a dc to dc converter, I thought of using a "flybuck" circuit, I stopped at the IC "AOZ3015AI" (https://www.tme.eu/Document/0262838228a45307035e45b4effa9bb7/AOZ3015AI-DTE.pdf), due to the price accessible. My question is if this circuit is compatible with this application, what features should I pay attention to?

I need for: U1: -20v   / I = 50 mA.
U2: 3v AC / I = 100 mA.

Example "Flybuck" circuit:

[image]

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 - you are mistaken. The poster’s circuit is indeed a “flybuck” it is also not synchronous as it uses D1 not an active switching device.

Comment: I stand corrected. New name to me.  https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva790/snva790.pdf?ts=1649077713175  You need better specs for input and tolerance of output then re-read design info until understood